# Flash Builder Not Recognizing Keyboard Input In A TextField

Tags: actionscript-3, input, textfield

This is really very bizarre and I've wasted too much time on this - the following code works in a .fla perfectly (Flash Pro project), but when I try and use it in my ActionScript Project compiled with Flash Builder the input textfield doesn't recognize or display the new text.  Even setting up eventhandlers to track the change do not work. I can use this.tf.text = 'blah' and it will work, but it will not accept user input.

```
this.tf = new TextField();
this.tf.x = 100;
this.tf.y = 100;
this.tf.width = 100;
this.tf.height = 20;
this.tf.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
this.tf.restrict = null;
this.addChild(this.tf);
```

Has anyone come across this before?  I've uninstalled Flash Builder Pro and reinstalled it, too.

Comment: Are there any differences at all between your Flash Pro project and the Flash Builder project? Is it possible there is something on the display list "in front of" the `TextField` that could be blocking user input?

Comment: Something is a front of it or you are publishing for mobile, one of those.

Comment: Nope - I can select the text, but can't edit it with the keyboard input, only programatically. I built a simple app with basically just the code above - ran it in Flash Pro, worked.  Compiled it in Flash Builder, nope

Comment: And I just tried compiling with the 3.6 SDK and it still won't work

Comment: Try to run compiled SWF in standalone FlashPlayer, not browser. Works?

Comment: That worked - but my concern is that if my app has to run in a web browser, I'm still in trouble.  I need to fix this.

Comment: Ok - I solved this thanks to subdan - It wasn't working in Safari, tried it in Chrome and no problem.  Subdan - add yours as an answer so I can accept it